# Python 3.8: Unable to install matplotlib on Windows

Tags: python, installation, pip, pycharm, python-3.8

I am trying to install matplotlib on PyCharm and I am getting the following error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\matplotlib\
```

I tried:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install updates
```

Also updated PyCharm but nothing is working.

Comment: What is your version of Python, pip, PyCharm, and OS?

Comment: Python 3.8, pip 19.0.3, PyCharm 2020.2.3, Windows 10 Version 1803

Comment: Please post the full error, not jsut the last line